# Mailchimp RSS campaigns with multiple feeds and groups

Tags: rss, mailchimp, feed, cherry-pick

I need a Mailchimp expert to give me some insights about how to achieve the following:

I need to create RSS Campaigns in Mailchimp, which should be send to users, that are subscribed to specific topics (that is implemented with Groups). The problem is that if the user is subscribed to more than one topic, he should receive only one email, combining the feeds from all the selected topics. What is the way to create a campaign, which sends to the users only feeds that their are interested in, combining them into single email?

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid this is not a StackOverflow question... more a Power User or Web Applications one.
Mailchimp doesn't allow multifeed newsletters (in fact yes but only for a fixed number of items in each feed... not suitable to put only new items in a multithematic newsletter). I only know FlipRSS that can solve the problem.

Comment: Actually I got to the same conclusion.. what I did in the end is to implement a service that creates custom campaigns by segments  and trigger this service in a cron job.